# what is special about simplexes?

Tags: geometry, polytopes, convex-geometry

Is it true that the $d$-simplex is the only convex polytope such that

1. All vertexes share an edge with all others,
2. It is transitive under the action of a group?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: I know that in 3 dimensions this is true, but am not sure in higher dimensions. Indeed in 3 dimensions I think the only convex polytope that satisfies 1. is a simplex

Comment: @jdizzle About 3 dimension, you are right. The only 2-neighborly 3-dimensional polytope is a tetrahedron. But for higher dimensions there are counterexamples. Take $P$ to be product of two triangles. Its Polar is a 2-neighborly (property 1 of your question) 4-polytope with 6 vertices which is not a simplex.